# How to expose secured Nifi URL

Tags: apache-nifi

How we can use listenhttp processor for securing the NiFi url with username and password for post data on nifi.please help me out.
Thanks

Comment: Are you asking to use the listenhttp processor to secure NIFI logins? By default, NiFi uses a single username and password, but one can use other methods to change the login such as LDAP. Check the Admin Guide for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Which version of NiFi are you using?
In NiFi 1.14.0 it introduced security for logins by, “NiFi now starts up in a mode enabling security features by default.  This means NiFi starts up with HTTPS only now instead of HTTP and it requires a specific auto generated username and password to login or the user can explicitly set the username and password which will be used via the provided toolkit.  Gone are the days of firing a default NiFi and it is accessible via HTTP without authentication.  That convenience was wonderful but we found far too many users did this and left wide open NiFi nodes and even clusters accessible on the Internet.  Our secure configuration by default model generates a self-signed server certificate which obviously means that itself isn't very trustworthy for any given client so your browser will likely flag this but we're taking reasonable steps in the right direction.  All the normal recommended security steps are still recommended to ensure a fully secure setup but the default mode is now far better than ever before.”